# Dereferencing a multi-level hash: A practical example

Tags: perl, hash, dereference, multi-level

I have a data that I pump into this multi-level hash:

```
$newcomm_stat_hash{$stat_message_class}{$stat_process} = $stat_host;
```

I can print out the `$stat_message_class`, and the `$stat_process` with the 
keys-values structure:

```
foreach my $stat_message_class (keys %newcomm_stat_hash) {

   my $stat_message_type = $stat_message_class;

   foreach my $stat_process (keys %{$newcomm_stat_hash{$stat_message_class}} ) {

      print $stat_host;
   }
}
```

But when I follow the same format to print out `$stat_host values` (see code below), I get this error message:

> Can't use string ("dc109") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at multilevel_hash line 24.

I get the same message for the keys or values function.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings; 
use strict;

my %newcomm_stat_hash; 
my $control_server = "dc100";
my $control_stat_message = "OCCD2o";

$newcomm_stat_hash{'OCCD2o'} =  { 'filesrvr' => 'dc100',
                                  'dhcpsrv'  => 'dc100',
                                  'dnssrv'   => 'dc109',
                                  'mailpfd'  => 'dc100',
                                };

$newcomm_stat_hash{'PIDmon2'} = { 'pingstat' => 'fg100',
                                  'udpmon'   => 'fg100',
                                  'ftp'      => 'dc100',
                                  'casper'   => 'dc440',
                                };

foreach my $stat_message_class ( keys %newcomm_stat_hash ) {

 my $stat_message_type = $stat_message_class;

 foreach my $stat_process ( keys %{$newcomm_stat_hash{$stat_message_class}} ) {

         foreach my $stat_host (keys %{$newcomm_stat_hash{$stat_message_class}{$stat_process}} ) {

             print $stat_host;
         } 
     }
}
```

After dereferencing the multilevel hash to `$stat_host` I want to plug this in at the end:

```
use TERM::ANSIColor;

if ($stat_host ne $control_server) {

    print "$stat_host, $stat_process , $stat_message_class";   
}   

elsif (  ($stat_host ne $control_server)
      && ($stat_message_class eq $control_stat_message)
      ) {   

    print color 'red';   
    print "$stat_host, $stat_process , $stat_message_class";
    print color 'reset';   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code correctly your saying that `OCCD2o` is a "message class", `filesrvr` is a "process" and `dc100` is the "host". If thats the case then the innermost "foreach" loop is not necessary, since you are already at the "host"-level of your hash-of-hashrefs. You can't go deeper at that level.

So if you rewrite the expression `%{$newcomm_stat_hash{$stat_message_class} {$stat_process}}` as:

```perl
$tmp = $newcomm_stat_hash{$stat_message_class}{$stat_process}
$hash = %{$tmp}
```

then `$tmp` gets evaluated to a string-scalar `dc109` which cant be dereferenced as hash thus the error-message is shown.

I would say this is the correct loop-structure:

```perl
foreach my $stat_message_class(keys %newcomm_stat_hash){
    my $stat_hash = $newcomm_stat_hash{$stat_message_class};
    my $stat_message_type = $stat_message_class;
    foreach my $stat_process (keys %{$stat_hash}){
        my $stat_host = $stat_hash->{$stat_process};

        print $stat_message_class, " / ", $stat_process, " / ", $stat_host, "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the objective here is to print in the hash entry that correspond to `$control_server` and `$control_stat_message` in red.

If so, the conditional will not do what you want it to, because the `elsif` clause will *never* execute.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings; 
use strict;
use Term::ANSIColor;

my %newcomm_stat_hash; 
my $control_server       = "dc100";
my $control_stat_message = "OCCD2o";

$newcomm_stat_hash{'OCCD2o'} =  { 'filesrvr' => 'dc100',
                                  'dhcpsrv'  => 'dc100',
                                  'dnssrv'   => 'dc109',
                                  'mailpfd'  => 'dc100',
                                };

$newcomm_stat_hash{'PIDmon2'} = { 'pingstat' => 'fg100',
                                  'udpmon'   => 'fg100',
                                  'ftp'      => 'dc100',
                                  'casper'   => 'dc440',
                                };

foreach my $stat_message_class ( keys %newcomm_stat_hash ) {

    my $message_class = $newcomm_stat_hash{$stat_message_class};

    foreach my $stat_process ( keys %{ $message_class } ) {

        my $host = $message_class->{$stat_process};

        my $info = join(', ', $stat_message_class, $stat_process, $host) . "\n";

        if (   $stat_message_class eq $control_stat_message
           &&  $host eq $control_server
           )
        {

            print colored ( $info, 'red' );  # Prints $info in red
        }

        else {

            print $info;                     # Prints $info normally
        }
    }
}
```